# Inherited Interface if Unimplemented = Abstract class?

Tags: inheritance, interface, abstract

I have a doubt, if at all the inherited interface members are not implemented then the derived results is an abstract class?

If so can I create an instance of that interface given that the underlying derived class is an abstract?

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

Q: extend interfaces but leaving them unimplemented, is that an abstract class?

A: If you want to compile a class that that leaves interfaces unimplemented then that class *has* to be an abstract class, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Q: Can I create an instance of that interface ...

A: stop right there - you cannot create instances of interfaces. You can also not create instances of abstract classes. That class has to be ['concrete'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211317/how-is-abstract-class-different-from-concrete-class) before you can instantiate it.

Please review these other SO Questions:

- [Abstract class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java).
- [What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class).
- [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo).

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete class all members of an interface must be defined, with abstract classes you can mark the members as abstract and let a concrete class that derives from it, define the methods.

Instances can only be created from concrete classes, however you can access these instance objects using a interface or abstract class reference.

```
Interface a = new InterfaceImplementation();
a.SomeInterfaceMethod();
```

Against this is typical across languages, but will vary depending on the language in question, I.e. Some languages are single paradigm, such as purely functional.